# Scheduled Local Notifications showing up when toggled ON for time period when toggled OFF

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have a **daily scheduled notification** at 8:30:01 PM.

When the Notifications are toggled *OFF* in Settings app for a week, no notifications show up, which is perfect.

The **problem is when Notifications are toggled back *ON*** in Settings app after that week, **all of the Notifications for the previous week show up**.

I was wondering how to get Notifications to not "build up" so to speak.

Is there a line of code I'm missing in here to "clear them out"?

**`ViewController.m`**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    comp.hour = 20; // 19 = 7PM  20=8pm
    comp.minute = 30; // 7:45 PM  8:30
    comp.second = 01; // 7:45:01 PM

    localNotification.fireDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Local Notification in iOS8";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

***These are Notifications that show from when Notifications was *OFF*, as soon as I toggle Notifications back *ON*:***

[image]

Comment: When setting button to off, do you clean the already scheduled notifications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the notifications to OFF, you should call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];`

Comment: Ah!  So add that one line to clear the notifications.  Quick question, is there a line I need for setting all the notifications to OFF?  Or is all I need that line to clear notifications?

Comment: is it recommended to put it BEFORE or AFTER `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];`?

Comment: Because right now I have it after that line, and I'm not getting the notification firing (and Notifications are toggled on)

Comment: And when I put it before that line, its doing the same thing (showing notification when turned back ON) that I wrote the question for

Comment: It's not at the same place, it's in your "off" case.

You've got to to a "if(switchIsOn) { register notificcation } else { cancel local notifications }"

Comment: Ahh.  Didn't realize that was another part.  How would you go about doing the `switchIsOn` part?  Thats part of the problem I'm not getting then, how you tell if the switch is ON or OFF

Comment: And are you still doing all of this in the `ViewController` or does any of this go in the `AppDelegate`?