# iOS : Notification scheduled in past showing up on enabling from settings through "Allow Notifications"

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, uilocalnotification

Here is my scenario:

- I scheduled a local notification for 4:02 PM at 4:00 PM
- disabled the notifications from settings thru "Allow Notifications"
- as expected, the notification does not show up at 4:02 PM
- At 4:04 PM, when I enable the notifications from settings thru "Allow Notifications", I am receiving the past notification (set for 4:02 PM) immediately.

I found this thread:
[Scheduled Local Notifications showing up when toggled ON for time period when toggled OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956882/scheduled-local-notifications-showing-up-when-toggled-on-for-time-period-when-to), this does not solve my purpose as its asking to clear the scheduled notifications. This will not be possible when my application is not running.

Is there any way the past notification do not show up?

Answer (score 0):

When your changin your notification allow status;

Cancel all local notifications with this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Cancel one local notification with this line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:theNotification];
```

If you want to keep your future notifications delete for a parameter your local notifications. Otherwise you allow notifications again you can't see any notification because you deleted all of them.

Comment: and what exactly should I do if my app is not running?

Comment: If your app is not running than you can't on/off your notifications. When you change your notification permission status use this methods.